# Replacing values in array from netCDF

Tags: python, arrays, netcdf

```
masked_array(data =
 [[[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  ..., 
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]]

 [[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  ..., 
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]]

 [[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  ..., 
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]]

 ..., 
 [[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  ..., 
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]]

 [[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  ..., 
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]]

 [[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  ..., 
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]]],
             mask =
 [[[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  ..., 
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]]

 [[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  ..., 
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]]

 [[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  ..., 
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]]

 ..., 
 [[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  ..., 
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]]

 [[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  ..., 
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]]

 [[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  ..., 
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]]],
       fill_value = 9e+20)
```

I am reading the above masked array from a netCDF file. The first slice looks like this:

```
val[0].data
array([[  8.99999983e+20,   8.99999983e+20,   8.99999983e+20, ...,
          8.99999983e+20,   8.99999983e+20,   8.99999983e+20],
       [  8.99999983e+20,   8.99999983e+20,   8.99999983e+20, ...,
          8.99999983e+20,   8.99999983e+20,   8.99999983e+20],
       [  8.99999983e+20,   8.99999983e+20,   8.99999983e+20, ...,
          8.99999983e+20,   8.99999983e+20,   8.99999983e+20],
       ..., 
       [  8.99999983e+20,   8.99999983e+20,   8.99999983e+20, ...,
          8.99999983e+20,   8.99999983e+20,   8.99999983e+20],
       [  8.99999983e+20,   8.99999983e+20,   8.99999983e+20, ...,
          8.99999983e+20,   8.99999983e+20,   8.99999983e+20],
       [  8.99999983e+20,   8.99999983e+20,   8.99999983e+20, ...,
          8.99999983e+20,   8.99999983e+20,   8.99999983e+20]], dtype=float32)
```

How do I replace the 8.99999983e+20 values by 0.0? I thought that these are fill_values but using `ma.set_fill_value(val, 0.0)` does not work (it only changes `fill_value to 0.0, but doesn't change 8.99999983e+20

Comment: Have you tried regular numpy-based replacement? e.g. `val[val > 1e20] = 0.0`

Comment: thanks @N1B4, that does work. If you can write it as answer, I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cool thing with masked arrays is that data and mask are separated. The `fill_value` attribute only affects the `filled()` method of a masked array, not the data:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.ma.array([1, 2, 3, 4], mask=[0, 0, 1, 1])
>>> x
masked_array(data = [1 2 -- --],
             mask = [False False  True  True],
       fill_value = 999999)

>>> x.filled()
array([     1,      2, 999999, 999999])
>>> x.set_fill_value(-999)
>>> x.filled()
array([   1,    2, -999, -999])
>>> x.data
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

In your case

```
val.set_fill_value(0)
print val.filled()
```

or just `val.filled(0)` should do the trick.